# Linked Server query is not working properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

How to create a linked Server Query

Server1 name is `Server`, Table name is `Employee`
Server2 name is `RAPAN`, Table name is `Venus`

I want to select a venus table (server2) through server1.

How to do this through query

Tried Query

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 
   @server = 'server', 
   @srvproduct = '',
   @provider = 'SQLOLEDB', 
   @datasrc = 'RAPAN'
GO
```

Query Executed Successfully, But when it try to `select * from venus` through server1, it's giving error as `invalid object name`

What wrong in my query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should add login mapping to this server
- You should query with full naming convention like `SELECT * FROM server1.RAPAN.dbo.venus`

To add linked server use (**and play with options on your needs**):

```
EXEC sys.sp_addlinkedserver @server = 'RAPAN', @srvproduct = 'SQL Server'
```

**Set optional options**

```
EXEC sys.sp_serveroption @server = 'RAPAN', @optname = 'collation compatible', @optvalue = 'On'
EXEC sys.sp_serveroption @server = 'RAPAN', @optname = 'data access', @optvalue = 'On'
EXEC sys.sp_serveroption @server = 'RAPAN', @optname = 'lazy schema validation', @optvalue = 'On' 
EXEC sys.sp_serveroption @server = 'RAPAN', @optname = 'rpc', @optvalue = 'On'
EXEC sys.sp_serveroption @server = 'RAPAN', @optname = 'rpc out', @optvalue = 'On'
```

**Add login [(And read more)](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=sp_addlinkedsrvlogin&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189811.aspx&ei=umAeT_yBLsLn8QOH1ZScDg&usg=AFQjCNEJo8BEov4T1MRCAP52GROUVIlzLg&sig2=Ri4kfHFYYSUJHMTpUhc3lQ)**

```
EXEC sys.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = 'RAPAN'
```

Comment: I added like this EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'RAPAN', 'false',  'sa', 'sa'.  Executed successfully, but when i try to run this query "Select * from server1.RAPAN.dbo.venus", showing error as "Login failed for sa"

Comment: Your remote sa has a password **sa** ?

Comment: EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'RAPAN', 'false', 'sa', 'sa', 'remotesapassword'

Comment: i am not using remotepassword.

Comment: But it still exists. If it empty, then use empty string ''

Comment: EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = 'RAPAN', executed successfully, but when i run the query, showing error as login failed for sa...

Comment: Thats because your remote server has password for login sa - you need to provide it